# Dart pub build mode not working

Tags: command-line, sdk, dart

I'm trying to get Dart's `pub build` to run without minifying the generated JavaScript. According to [this page](http://pub.dartlang.org/doc/pub-build.html) I should be able to run it like so:

```
pub build --mode=debug
```

...which will force `pub build` to use the no-minify option.

However, when I run that, I get:

```
Could not find an option named "mode".
Run "pub help" to see available options.
```

Running `Pub 1.0.0+10.r30798` - any ideas?

Comment: The content on the page is right, but only for users of the dev channel version. Users of the stable release need to use the old --no-minify option for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running `pub build --no-minify`.

```
$ pub help build

Copy and compile all Dart entrypoints in the 'web' directory.

Usage: pub build [options]
-h, --help           Print usage information for this command.
    --[no-]minify    Minify generated JavaScript.
                     (defaults to on)
```

Comment: Thanks @Claudio d'Angelis (+1) - are those old docs I was reading? Also, `no-minify` doesn't seem to actually work (although it certainly runs). When I view the `myapp.dart.js` file, it still looks obfuscated and minified - thoughts?

Comment: @TicketMonster if you want to make sure minification is working, try comparing file sizes before and after `--no-minify`.
If it looks obfuscated, minified or generally not-human readable it is because it's generated code.

Answer (score 1):

You can turn off js minification by adding a [dart2js transformer](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/dart2js-transformer.html) in your pubspec.

For example

```
transformers:
- $dart2js:
   minify: false
```